# is it possible to trigger two events at once

Tags: jquery

```
objb.on('focus', function() {
    some code
});

objb.on('keydown', function() {
    same code as above
});
```

To avoid the repeating I tried:

```
objb.on('focus, keydown', function() {
    some code
});
```

Doesn't work. Is it possible this way?

Comment: Remove the comma between events just use a space delimiter.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on `One or more *space-separated* event types`

Answer (score 5):

Almost - when you want to use `.on` to listen for multiple events, separate the event names with a *plain space*, not a comma:

```js
const objb = $('.objb');
objb.on('focus keydown', function() {
  console.log('listener running');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="objb"></textarea>
```